# Web Scraping <td> tag issue - Python 3 With Lxml

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am web scraping in python with the lxml library. And, am trying to scrape some data off of the baseball site http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/standings/exhibition.jsp?ymd=20161002.
For some reason my code prints an empty list after what I printed before . Any help on this issue would be great!

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/standings/exhibition.jsp?ymd=20161002')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
#This will create a list of buyers:
##buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//td[@class="tg_w"]/text()')

print("Wins: ", prices)
print()
##print("Buyers: ", buyers)
```

Comment: my guess is that page you're fetching doesn't contain the table elements (td), they're loaded by javascript/ajax, so you may look for api of mlb.mlb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML != XML. Some html5 tags will probably mess with the XML parser.

Try [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with the parser set to [`html5lib`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Comment: Not quite, `lxml.html` actually is an HTML parser: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html. Also, parsing malformed XML with an XML parser would return an error instead of empty results.

Comment: @MathiasMüller This is true. The parser is successfully parsing the html5 but some selfclosing tags like `<br>` or `<input>` will screw up the structure. If you set the bs4 parser to `lxml` and then pretty print the result you will see exactly that.

Comment: No, self-closing tags do not screw up the structure, not even in XML and self-closing (or unclosed) element tags are not the problem here. Likely explanations for the problem described in the question are a) the element is generated by Javascript or b) the target element is in a namespace.